# Using a method to create enum values

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum:
`public enum X implements Y`

I also have a class
`Ybuilder` which can create instances of `Y`, let's say with `Ybuilder.create(int value)`

How can I set the enum values in my enum to be instances of `Y` created with `Ybuilder`?  ideally it would be something simple like

```
public enum X implements Y {
  A (Ybuilder.create(0)),
  B (Ybuilder.create(1)),
};
```

Comment: `X` should have a constructor that takes `Y` as parameter type

Comment: What should that constructor do or set?

Comment: depends on what you want , you can have instance members of type `T` that you can set

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do it that way - one alternative would be to delegate to the Y instance created by the builder. For example:

```
interface Y { //Assume Y has two methods
   void m1();
   void m2();
}

public enum X implements Y {
  A (0),
  B (1);
  private final Y y;
  X(int value) { this.y = YBuilder.create(value); }

  //Then delegate to y to implement the Y interface

  public void m1() { y.m1(); return; }
  public void m2() { y.m2(); return; }
};
```

---

Note that I created the enums with the `int` argument but you can pass a `Y` directly if you prefer:

```
public enum X implements Y {
  A (Ybuilder.create(0)),
  B (Ybuilder.create(1));
  private final Y y;
  X(Y y) { this.y = y; }
};
```

Comment: Is there a way to not have to implement all of Y's methods?  Y actually has a lot of methods and it's annoying for this enum to have a bunch of methods that just return y.method();

Comment: @AndrewLatham it looks a lot like enums aren't necessarily right for this use case; that you actually just want a bunch of constants.

Comment: Of course, there is a way not to have to implement all of Y's methods. Just don’t let `X` implement `Y`. Just add *one* method to `X` to get the `Y` instance and you’re done.